My Proteus 8.6 is showing "Packaging 'NULL' of device 'LOGICSTATE' not found."
I am trying to make a project using 8051 and PIR sensor, and when I am simulating it I encountered a error stating
Invalid opcode Invalid opcode 0xFFE3 at PC=0x0004

So, when I checked the verify packaging in Proteus it is showing me this:-
Packaging 'NULL' of device 'LOGICSTATE' not found.
Processed 4 devices and 4 packagings
1 errors found

So I think the problem is with the logicstate, I didn't tried anything search the internet but didn't find any solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Since Proteus is an hardware design and simulation tool, you may get more expertise at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  The only clearly software related issue here is the invalid opcode, but all that indicates is that the program counter got to 0x004 where there was no valid instruction.  Normally the reset vector 0x0000 would have a LJMP instruction to your code entry point and you would never get to PC=0x004, so I guess you have no valid code loaded.  0x0004 is the second byte of the INT0 vector - you should not have ended up with PC=0x0004 under any normal circumstances.
